# Variable names in phpMyAdmin bookmark

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have created a couple of bookmarks with a single variable in phpMyAdmin now, which does not pose a problem. Single variable and a somewhat descriptive name and it is possible to know what the variable 'becomes'

The problem I have is when there are more variables in the query. Something like the following:

```
/*SET @id = [VARIABLE1]*/; 
/*SET @date = [VARIABLE2]*/;
DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id = @id AND date = @date;
DELETE FROM table2 WHERE id = @id AND date = @date;
SELECT @id, @datum;
```

`Variable 1` and `Variable 2` are not really descriptive names. Is it possible to use other names for it? I have tried the following

```
/*SET @id = [ID]*/;
/*SET @date = [DATE]*/;
```

and

```
/*SET @id = [VARIABLEID]*/;
/*SET @date = [VARIABLEDATE]*/;
```

Both of those do not have any effect, and it seems they don't even get recognized as variables.

Is it possible to use named variables for a bookmark, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable names in bookmarks must be as follow: `[VARIABLE{variable-number}]`

see the [official phpMyAdmin documentation](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/bookmarks.html).

It's not really a problem since you're assigning those values to your own variables (`/*SET @date = [VARIABLE2]*/;`).

Comment: So pretty much, no it is not possible to change the variable name to anything other than variable1 etc.
I did indeed see the official documentation, I did however hope that it was possible but accidentally not included in the documentation